# display of a datagrid view

Tags: c#, datagridview, distinct

I'm trying to get the distinct values of each column in my datagridview in a label.text but it didnt work can any one help me.

for example:

```
hair | age |friendly 
red  |old  | yes         
black|young| no
black|old  | maybe
```

results should be displayed in a label.text like this : hair: red, black; age: old, young ; friendly: yes, no, maybe.

Thanks in advance for all your time. Regards

Comment: I used dataTable (named dt) to fill my datagridview . Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 0):

If i understood you correctly this is one aproach(where dt is your datatable):

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> distinct = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();
foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
{
     distinct.Add(col.ColumnName, new List<string>());
     DataTable uniqueCols = dt.DefaultView.ToTable(true, col.ColumnName);
     distinct[col.ColumnName]
                           .AddRange(uniqueCols.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(x => x.ItemArray).Cast<string>());
}

StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
foreach (KeyValuePair<string, List<string>> pair in distinct)
{
     b.Append(pair.Key + ": ");
     foreach (var item in pair.Value)
     {
        b.Append(item + " ");
     }
}

label1.Text = b.ToString();
```

Comment: HI Sir thx for your fast reply. how can i display the content of the query in a label.text to see if it gives the correct results. Thanks

Comment: Hi Sir I really appreciate all your time and support thx alot. However the code didnt work it just highlights this line "[col.ColumnName]
                                      .AddRange(uniqueCols.AsEnumerable().SelectMany(x => x.ItemArray).Cast<string>());" with yellow and it says "Unable to cast an object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'."